# Acceder a los atributos de una clase desde un metodo de otra

Tags: c++, clase

Estoy comenzado con C++, quisiera saber como utilizar los atributos de una clase en otra, por ejemplo, el atributo `CostoBase` debo utilizarlo en el metodo `PrecioVenta()`, intente crear una variable en la clase `Venta` e igualarla al metodo `setCostoBase`, de manera que pudiera usar lo que obtengo en dicho metodo pero me sigo dando error.

```
class Producto {
    private:
        string Codigo;
        float CostoBase; // necesito utilizarlo en la 2da clase
    public:
        Producto ( );
        void setCodigo(string codigo);
        void setCostoBase( float costo);
        string getCodigo( );
        float getCostoBase( );
};

class Venta {
    private:
        int CantProdVend;
        string TipoVenta;
    public:
        Venta( );
        void setCantProdVend(int cantidad);
        void setTipoVenta (string tipo);
        int getCantProdVend( );
        string getTipoVenta( );
        float PrecioVenta( ); // aqui la debo utilizar
        float VentaTotal( );
}; 
________________________________________________________________________________

float Venta::PrecioVenta( ) {
    float precio;
    if (TipoVenta == "Detal") {
        precio = (CostoBase * 0.30) + CostoBase;
        return precio;
    } else if ( TipoVenta== "Mayor") {
        precio= (CostoBase * 0.15) + CostoBase;
        return precio;
    } else {
        precio= 0;
        return precio;}

}
```

Siguiendo las sugerencias que me dieron cree e instancie un nuevo objeto de la clase producto y lo pase por parametro en la funcion PrecioVenta, pero ahora me genera un error en la siguiente funcion VentaTotal:

Me falto modificar algo en la declaracion de la clase?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Producto {
    private:
        string Codigo;
        float CostoBase;
    public:
        Producto ( );
        void setCodigo(string codigo);
        void setCostoBase( float costo);
        string getCodigo( );
        float getCostoBase( );
};


class Venta {
    private:
        int CantProdVend;
        string TipoVenta;
    public:
        Venta( );
        void setCantProdVend(int cantidad);
        void setTipoVenta (string tipo);
        int getCantProdVend( );
        string getTipoVenta( );
        float PrecioVenta(Producto elProducto);
        float VentaTotal();
};
```

La implementacion de los metodos:

```
#include "venta_producto.h"

Producto::Producto( ) { };

void Producto::setCodigo (string codigo) {
    Codigo = codigo;
}
    string Producto::getCodigo( ) {
    return Codigo;
}
void Producto::setCostoBase( float costo) {
    CostoBase = costo;
}
float Producto::getCostoBase ( ) {
    return CostoBase;
}

Venta::Venta( ) { };

void Venta::setCantProdVend (int cantidad) {
    CantProdVend = cantidad;
}
int Venta::getCantProdVend( ) {
    return CantProdVend;
}
void Venta::setTipoVenta(string tipo) {
    TipoVenta = tipo;
}
string Venta::getTipoVenta( ) {
    return TipoVenta;
}
float Venta::PrecioVenta(Producto  elProducto) {
 float costo = elProducto.getCostoBase();
    float precio;
    if (TipoVenta == "Detal") {
        precio = (costo * 0.30) + costo;
        return precio;
    } else if ( TipoVenta== "Mayor") {
        precio= (costo * 0.15) + costo;
        return precio;
    } else {
        precio= 0;
        return precio;}

}
float Venta::VentaTotal() {
    float total;
    total = PrecioVenta(Producto elProducto) * CantProdVend;// aca se genera el error:  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'elProducto'
    return total;
}
```

principal.cpp:

```
#include "venta_producto.h"
#include <iostream>

    void IEProducto (Producto & elProducto);
    void IEVenta (Venta & laVenta);
    void IS (Producto elProducto, Venta laVenta);

int main () {

    Producto elProducto;
    Venta laVenta;

    IEProducto (Producto & elProducto);
    IEVenta (Venta & laVenta);
    IS (Producto elProducto, Venta laVenta);

    return 0;
}

    void IEProducto (Producto & elProducto) {
        string codigo;
        float costo;

        cout << "Introduzca el codigo del producto: ";
        cin >> codigo;
        elProducto.setCodigo(codigo);

        cout << "Coloque el precio base del producto: ";
        cin >> costo;
        elProducto.setCostoBase(costo);

    }

    void IEVenta (Venta & laVenta) {
        int cantidad;
        string tipo;

        cout << "Introduzca la cantidad de productos a vender: ";
        cin >> cantidad;
        laVenta.setCantProdVend(cantidad);

        cout << "Coloque el tipo de venta segun cantidad de articulos a             
vender (Mayor/Detal): ";
        cin >> tipo;
        laVenta.setTipoVenta(tipo);

    }

    void IS (Producto elProducto, Venta laVenta) {

        cout << "el precio de venta por articulo es: " << 
laVenta.PrecioVenta(Producto elProducto);
        cout << "Monto a pagar: " << laVenta.VentaTotal();

    }
```

Comment: CostoBase es un atributo de Producto y no puedes llamarlo sin más. Para poder acceder a los atributos de una instancia de clase antes debes crearla. Saludos. David

Comment: Puedes cambiar en tu clase Venta la propiedad PrecioVenta y VentaTotal que en realidad son funciones a propiedades float's y en tu main usar esas funciones y asignarles a esas propiedades el resultado de esas variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El atributo CostoBase es un atributo de clase, lo que significa que necesitas crear un nuevo objeto/instancia de la clase Producto, luego lo que puedes hacer, es que en tu función Venta::PrecioVenta, pasarle por parametro ese objeto que creaste de Producto... Tu código entonces se veria algo más o menos asi:

```
float Venta::precioVenta(Producto* producto)
{
    // como ya tenemos una referencia al objeto producto ya podemos usar sus métodos
    float costoBase = producto->getCostoBase();

    if (this->tipoVenta == "Detal")
    {
        float precio = (costoBase * 0.30) + costoBase;
        return precio;
    }
    else if (this->tipoVenta == "Mayor")
    {
        float precio = (costoBase * 0.15) + costoBase;
        return precio;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

///
Siguiendo con la respuesta a el error de que te lanza..., y en teoria las modificaciones que le has hecho a tu función Venta::PrecioVenta.
Recuerda que la función Venta::PrecioVenta, recibe como párametro una instancia de la clase Producto, la cual no se la estas pasando cuando invoncas a la función en Venta::VentaTotal, es por eso que te dice "not match", que significa que no hay niguna función que coincida con esa firma de función.

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, ahora me surge otro problema en el metodo que sigue:
 
     float Venta::VentaTotal( ) {
        float total;
 total = PrecioVenta() * CantProdVend; /*[Error] no matching 
     function for call to "Venta::PrecioVenta()"*/
 return total; }
El metodo que sigue deberia totalizar con la cantidad de productos vendidos * el precio de venta (PrecioVenta())

Comment: Si te soy sincero no logro enteneder tu pregunta... Intenta poner me tu código para hecharle una revisada... Gracias.

Comment: edite la pregunta y coloque el codigo que genera el nuevo error, con respecto a la sugerencia que me hiciste, el nuevo objeto de la clase a instanciar, no debe ser necesariamente el mismo objeto que creo en la funcion main?, no se si me explique bien, pero en el main() por ejemplo, instancio un objeto de la clase Producto llamado elProducto, el nuevo objeto a instanciar en el metodo PrecioVenta puede llevar el mismo nombre o es indiferente?

Comment: @JuanCastillo, si estas instanciando un nuevo producto directamente desde la función, pueden llevar el mismo nombre, ya que son dos ambitos distintos...

Comment: intente tambien colocando la instancia en el parametro de la funcion PrecioVenta  cuando la invoco en VentaTotal pero me genera otro error ([Error] expected primary-expression before 'elProducto'), el cual no interpreto muy bien para conseguir alguna solucion

Comment: @JuanCastillo Me gustaria ver tu código para saber con claridad cual puede ser tu error, si pudess ponerme el codigo de tu función main tambien te lo agradeceria, y recuerda ponerme el código con los cambias que has hecho... Para asi saber si estamos en el mismo canal por asi decirlo...

Comment: edite la pregunta y coloque el codigo, no se si hay algun otro medio por aca para no colocar algo tan extenso, tambien quisiera saber si hay algun error de sintaxis en el principal.cpp con respecto a las interfaces de entrada y salida

Comment: @JuanCastillo si tienes algunos cuantos errores en tu sintaxis, de primero no estas importando el `using namespace std;` por lo que no puedes usar el cout, a seca, lo puedes usar como std::cout; dame unos minutos que refactorize y busque otros errores en el código y te informa de ello;

Comment: disclupame, si estoy usando el espacio de nombres pero no me percate que no se coloco en la edicion de la pregunta, no me tardo en correjirlo

Comment: Tienes más, algunos plobemas con respecto a ue para crear las instancias debes tener tus objetos creados con `new Clase();`

Comment: En Venta::PrecioVenta, el tipo de parametro deberia de ser un puntero a producto, Algo como asi `Venta::PrecioVenta(Producto* elProducto) {}`

Comment: Para acceder a las propiedades de de los punteros usa: `puntero->Metodo()`, y te recomiendo mucho que uses el puntero this, no estoy tan seguro de que si es o no obligatoria, pero aveces usarlo te puede aydar a corregir algunos errores

Comment: por lo visto tengo mas errores de los que pensaba, si me puedes mencionar los conceptos en los que falle (o que no tuve claros) en este ejercicio de  POO te lo agradeceria, creo que me falta estudiar mas y seguir investigando

Comment: Esos fueron algunos errores más significativos que encorre. Te recomiendo que sigues investigando un poco más sobre los tipo y como crear instancias de clases, que veo que son algunos problemas que tienes en tu código, estudia más sobre las referencias y punteros, y sus diferencias y similitudes... Creo que también necesitas dominar un poco más el puntero this, como acceder a propiedades de punteros. Y el paso de parametros por referencia y valor.